# Help center text references a thread but doesn't indicate which one

Tags: discussion, support, help-center

In the "What about open problems?" section of https://mathoverflow.net/help, the last line says "To join the discussion about how MathOverflow should deal with open problems, go to this meta.MO thread." However, there is no indication of which thread is referenced - neither a title of a thread nor a link. I suspect that it means [What should be the policy on "open problems" on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/360/what-should-be-the-policy-on-open-problems-on-mo) (especially since the whole section seems copied from an answer there, and the link in that answer points to that thread again).

Edited to add: the entire help center seems to be lacking links present in the answers it is copied from (e.g. https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/206), not just this one section, with the exception of the explanation of MO's corporate structure at the end.

Comment: When I look [at the FAQ](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/203/frequently-asked-questions-mathoverflow-faq/205#205) this post is linked there: [What should be the policy on “open problems” on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/360) Interestingly, the FAQ post has score -1.

Comment: Looking at the Wayback Machine, it seems that the help center looked differently [in June](https://web.archive.org/web/20210606050504/https://mathoverflow.net/help), but the text was already added at the [beginning of July](https://web.archive.org/web/20210701222358/https://mathoverflow.net/help). It seems that some older version of the FAQ was put there - for example, this problem is still there: [Update outdated links in the list of suggested alternative sites](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4053).

Comment: Just a suggestion - maybe you could also add ([meta-tag:discussion]) tag. In that way, the  question would become eligible for the [community bulletin](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-bulletin/info) and it would be more likely to get noticed. (Although in this case it is most important that it gets noticed by the mods - and they get notification about every new meta question in their moderator inbox anyway.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Done; I thought that this was more a quick-to-fix problem than one needing discussion, but you have more experience than I do.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether this was done by someone from the Stack Exchange staff or by a MO moderator. But eventually I managed to find the revision history: https://mathoverflow.net/posts/394744/revisions

Comment: Now the text was edited (and substantially shortened) by another moderator: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/edits-of-the-help-center-by-the-mo-moderators